# Can you see how many active downloads?

Tags: iphone, download, app-store-connect

I just recently put my first app up and I was wondering if there was a way to view how many ACTIVE downloads there are. I get that I can see how many total downloads I've gotten through iTunes Connect, but I see no way to know how many people still have the app on their device (not deleted).

I feel like this information is more beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that. However, you integrate something like Flurry to help you with analytics of future releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely look into that